# Merging two datasets with variables in one corresponding observations in the other

Tags: merge, stata, mergesort

I ran into a challenge today and I hope to get some help.
I want to `merge` 2 data sets. Dataset1 contains the member roster with 3 variables, the batch_id, member_num in the batch and occupation. Dataset2 consists of member license statuses.

The challenge here is that in dataset2 the member_num is represented as a variable in a way that member_num_x in dataset2 corresponds to "x" observation under variable member_num in dataset1. I need to `merge` these two datasets so that in the end I have one dataset that has batch_id, member_num, occupation, and license status for each member.

```
Dataset1
| batch_id   | member_num | occupation |
| --------   | --------   |  -------- 
| A01        |   1        | Driver     |
| A01        |   2        | Driver     |
| A01        |   3        | Driver     |
| A01        |   4        | Driver     |
| A02        |   1        | Navigator  |
| A02        |   2        | Navigator  |


Dataset2
| batch_id |member_num_1|member_num_2|member_num_3|member_num_4|
| -------- | --------   | --------   | --------   | --------   |         
| A01      | Yes        |   NA       |   Yes      |   No       | 
| A02      | No    |    |   NA       |


Desired Output 

| batch_id   | member_num | occupation | License_status
| --------   | --------   |  -------- 
| A01        |   1        | Driver     | Yes
| A01        |   2        | Driver     | NA
| A01        |   3        | Driver     | Yes
| A01        |   4        | Driver     | No
| A02        |   1        | Navigator  | No
| A02        |   2        | Navigator  | NA
```

I have tried using the `merge` command in Stata but there is no option to do this particular kind of merging. The options that are there use unique variables (almost same as joins on primary keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape d2 into long format and then merge/link on batch_id, member_num

### Approach 1 (using frames)

```
clear
use d1
frame create d2
frame d2: use d2
frame d2: reshape long member_num_, i(batch_id) j(member_num)
frlink 1:1 batch_id member_num, frame(d2)
frget License_status = member_num_, from(d2)
```

### Approach 2 (using merge)

```
clear
use d2
reshape long member_num_, i(batch_id) j(member_num)
rename member_num_ License_status
tempfile d2long
save `d2long',replace
use d1,clear
merge 1:1 batch_id member_num using `d2long',nogenerate keep(1 3)
```

### Output:

```
       batch_id   member~m   occupat~n   d2   Licens~s  
  1.        A01          1      Driver    1        Yes  
  2.        A01          2      Driver    2         NA  
  3.        A01          3      Driver    3        Yes  
  4.        A01          4      Driver    4         No  
  5.        A02          1   Navigator    5         No  
  6.        A02          2   Navigator    6         NA
```

### Input:

d1.dta:

```
       batch_id   member~m   occupat~n  
  1.        A01          1      Driver  
  2.        A01          2      Driver  
  3.        A01          3      Driver  
  4.        A01          4      Driver  
  5.        A02          1   Navigator  
  6.        A02          2   Navigator
```

d2.dta:

```
       batch_id   member~1   member~2   member~3   member~4  
  1.        A01        Yes         NA        Yes         No  
  2.        A02         No         NA
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a bunch for this. It worked very well. I just made one minor change since it was m:1 merge. regards

Comment: Just one question, why keep(1 3) ?

Comment: that makes it a left join; you would otherwise also have rows from d2 that don't match in d1

Answer (score 0):

The final answer with the minor edit:

```
clear 

use "Dataset2.dta" reshape long member_num_, i(batch_id) j(member_num) rename member_num_ License_status 
tempfile d2long 
save d2long',replace  

use "Dataset1.dta",clear  

merge m:1 batch_id member_num using d2long',nogenerate keep(1 3)
```